# Core Data Fetched Results Order

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting, core-data

I"m working with a core data model of Employees.  Each employee is assigned a building and a department.  I am returning everyone in building 1 with the predicate, building == 1 and using the sectionNameKeyPath parameter to break the result set down into groups by department.

Right now I have a sort descriptor ordering the departments alphabetically, but is there a way to ignore sorting them alphabetically and organize them in my own way, like engineers first, security second so on and so forth?  I'm still getting used to the terminology and there's probably something I'm overlooking.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `sortDescriptors` property of the fetched results controller is an array, so you can set multiple sort descriptors which will be used in the order you specify them (e.g. first by `department.name`, then by `lastName`, then by `firstName`).

Comment: So after my initial sortDescriptor of department, can I just put department == "Engineering" for descriptor 1, department == "Security" for descriptor 2, so on so forth, or is this incorrect?

Comment: Things like `department == "Engineering"` are predicates, those specify _which_ objects to fetch, not how to sort them. A sort descriptor is typically initialized like this: `[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"department" ascending:YES] autorelease]`

Comment: ok, i understand that i can sort by attributes, but how can i sort by the values of attributes, being that 'department' is a string attribute of the employee entity.  i don't care how the employees are sorted, i just want their groups to be sorted by my choosing

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. You always sort by the values of attributes. E.g., if you sort by department (if that's a string attribute), all employees in the "Accounting" department would be sorted before all the employees in the "Engineering" department.